# Sliding Fragment tabs with shared state

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I have a fragment which is hosting a **TabLayout**. I would like to have 2 tabs such that each of those is a fragment. I have been following this guide: 
https://guides.codepath.com/android/google-play-style-tabs-using-tablayout

The problem I am trying to solve is to have shared state or a way to communicate between the fragments - my 1st fragment will be hosting a list of Places (from Google place) and my 2nd fragment a map displaying them. My problem is that, when the data from the 1st fragment changes (e.g. filtered) the map fragment should also update its data. Ideally I wouldn't need to recreate the map if no changes have occurred in the list view.

In my **FragmentPagerAdapter** I have the following method which is retrieving the fragments but I can't figure out a way force fragment update/recreate if the state of the 1st fragment has changed

```
 @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        Fragment fragment = null;

        if(position == 0){
            fragment = findFragment(PlaceListFragment.getTAG());
            if(fragment == null) {
                fragment = PlaceListFragment.newInstance(0);
            }
            return fragment;

            }else{

            fragment = findFragment(MapViewFragment.getTAG());
            if(fragment == null) {
                fragment = MapViewFragment.newInstance();
            }
            return fragment;
        }

    }
```

Comment: If yo want to notify Second fragment of the changes in the first fragment, You can use broadcast receiver by registering action in second fragment and sending broadcast from first fragment considering the action and receiving it in second fragment. Or you can use Interface to notify the second fragment about the changes.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to detect hide/show then just override

```
public void onHiddenChanged(boolean hidden) {
   if(!hidden){
      //When fragment is visible
    }
    Log.i("my_fragment","setUserVisibleHint: "+isVisibleToUser);
}
```

or

```
 @Override
public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {
    super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);
    if(isVisibleToUser){
      //When fragment is visible
    }
    Log.i("my_fragment","setUserVisibleHint: "+isVisibleToUser);
}
```

in your fragment.